# Is it possible to use realm react-native as storage backend for redux persist

Tags: react-native, realm, redux

Am wondering if it is possible to use realm as the backend storage for redux-persist in react-native. Currently the project only lists AsyncStorage as an option for react-native.

Comment: I'm wondering the same - what did you find?

Comment: Haven't found an acceptable implementation/how to yet. Still waiting on this. The issues logged in Github relating to this integration is still open. I think the issue they are having is the deep copy which Realm doesn't currently support

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thanks @Gavin

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the docs, you can use any backend you want, as long as it implements the `setItem`, `getItem`, `removeItem`, `getAllKeys` methods.  I'm sure you could wire up an adapter to use realm.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the second part of your answer. Realm _is_ an on-disk store.

Comment: Oh, wow, I'm really embarrassed.  I completely forgot what Realm actually *was*.  Sorry!  Somehow I got it confused with something else.  I've deleted that second part of the answer.